# How to use Seed data with Paperclip + S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, paperclip, seed

I'm trying to seed my database with member profiles and also member profile pictures with S3 and paperclip but it doesn't seem to be working.

I can create/edit existing members within the application to add pictures with paperclip + S3 and it works just fine but seeding it doesn't work. I have searched but can't find an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know what is your exact problem but you can try something like this in your seeds.rb file :

```
u = User.new({:name => 'username', :email => 'user@name.fr'...})
u.avartar = File.open('/Users/myAccount/avatars/user.png')
u.save!
```

In your User.rb file, you must have parperclip configured to work with amazon s3

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
    :styles => { :large => "177x177>", :thumb => "60x60>" },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/avatars/:style/:id/:filename"
```

You could find on [dogan kaya berktas blog post](http://doganberktas.com/2010/09/14/amazon-s3-and-paperclip-rails-3/) detail about s3.yml

Comment: The idea of this could work but not when I push it up to heroku. I really want a way to just reference the pic with file.open('s3path.com') but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: It works for me but I run `rake db:seed` on my computer, not on heroku.