# Preventing duplicates when seeding with existing image using Paperclip + Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Every time I re-seed my database locally, duplicate images are being created in my Amazon S3 bucket. I think this is happening because I am not seeding correctly, but I don't know the proper way to do it. I've been using the method shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450207/how-to-use-seed-data-with-paperclip-s3). I'm using Rails 4, Ruby 2, paperclip 3.5.2, and aws-sdk 1.20.0.

You can see below in my `seeds.rb` file, I'm trying to set the image to the url of an image that has already been uploaded to the correct folder in my bucket. However, I think using `open()` here is causing a new, identical file to be saved to the same folder, usually something like http://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET_NAME/restaurants/images/1/original/open-uri20131111-22904-xvzitl.?1384211739.

EDIT: so my bucket will have both this file stored as well as http://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET_NAME/restaurants/images/1/original/NAME.jpg

Would really appreciate any help!

model

```
has_attached_file :image,
      :styles         => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
```

seeds.rb

```
Restaurant.create!( name:         ...,
                    description:  ...,
                    image:        open('https://s3.amazonaws.com/<BUCKET NAME>/restaurants/images/1/original/<NAME>.jpg') )
```

config/initializers/paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage]         = :s3
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_credentials]  = {
                                                            :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                                                            :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
                                                          }
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:bucket]          = ENV['AWS_BUCKET']
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url]             = ":s3_path_url"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path]            = "/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:default_url]     = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/<BUCKET NAME>/images/missing.png"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty late to the party on this one but I figure others may still be having the same problem. If you set the attachments on your models to nil before deleting them paperclip will delete them from S3.

Comment: I wish I could test this, but I don't know if I even have the app anymore. Thanks for the tip though!