# Seed with paperclip using image url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip and I want to upload the image on S3 for the User's avatar.

My CSV

```
username    avatar_url
foo         https://s3.amazonaws.com/foo/seed/10215716104_e09765dabd_z.jpg
```

I was going to [follow this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/arjunvenkat/1115bc41bf395a162084) to create a CSV, along with this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450207/how-to-use-seed-data-with-paperclip-s3) (for Paperclip seeding), so something like this:

```
require 'csv'

csv_text = File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'seeds', 'user.csv'))
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')
csv.each do |row|
  u = User.new
  u.username = row['username']
  u.avatar = File.open(row['avatar_url'])
  u.save
end
```

However, when I try this in the console, like this:

```
User.create(username: 'foo', avatar: File.new("https://s3.amazonaws.com/foo/seed/10215716104_e09765dab"))
```

I get an error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://s3.amazonaws.com/foo/seed/10215716104_e09765dabd_z.jpg
```

Is it possible to seed with images on S3?

Comment: shouldn't that be `File.open()`?

Comment: i've tried both.  but neither worked for me. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I'm using it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, ...
end

user = User.new
user.avatar = URI.parse(url_goes_here)
user.save
```

<sub>[Attachment downloaded from a URL](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Attachment-downloaded-from-a-URL)</sub>